# In active replication mode, import failover from data nodes

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

In active replication mode, import failover from data nodes
mode：3meta+2 (query+tskv)

```bash
load_cnosdb --file /home/benchmark/cnodb-iot-seed-123-scale-100-2021 --batch-size 20000 --workers 160 --urls http://192.168.0.23:8902
```

the log as follow:

```
[root@cnos19 cnosdb2.4.0.6c757da5e3]# load_cnosdb --file /home/benchmark/cnodb-iot-seed-123-scale-100-2021 --batch-size 20000 --workers 160 --urls http://192.168.0.23:8902
time,per. metric/s,metric total,overall metric/s,per. row/s,row total,overall row/s
1701163868,0.00,0.000000E+00,0.00,-,-,-
Error writing: [DebugInfo: worker #9, dest url: http://192.168.0.23:8902] Invalid write response (status 422): {"error_code":"050016","error_message":"Node failover: 2001, error: Status { code: Unknown, message: \"request timed out\", source: Some(Elapsed(())) }"}
```

#### To Reproduce

*No response*

#### Expected behavior

*No response*

#### Additional context

*No response*